# Maven Dependencies SpringBoot and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, spring-boot

we have web app with Spring Rest Controllers. We run on Spring Boot 1.5.8. We need to add MySQL database connector and all required dependencies. Here is our current pom.xml. We have tried many options without success. We have tried adding dependencies basen on mvndependencies.com. As well as getting done project and copying dependencies from it.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
        <artifactId>scribejava-apis</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly? Any error messages?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use spring boot data you need:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you want to add MySql support the only dependency you need is the MySql driver:

**EDIT: since 2022 there is a new driver**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

old driver:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Both dependencies versions should be managed by [spring boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml).